# SQL schema Site Leader Board

Tags: sql, database-design, mariadb

So I am trying to set up a site which has challenges and then want to convert that to leader boards for each challenge, and then an all time leaderboard.

So I have a challenges table that looks like this:

```
Challenge ID    Challenge Name  Challenge Date  Sport   Prize Pool
```

Then I need a way so each challenge has its own leader board of say 50 people.

linked by the challenge ID where that will = Leaderboard ID

I have a leader board of 50 people for that challenge that will look something like this:

```
Challenge ID     User             Place            Prize Won
```

My question is 2 things:

1. How can I make a table auto create when a new challenge is added to the challenges table?
2. How can I get an A site wide leader board for every challenge so it will show the following:

   ```
   Rank        USER          Prize Money Won(total every challenge placed)
   ```

   and then base rank order by how much money won..

I know this is a lot of questions all wrapped in one, schema design and logic.

Any insights greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than one table per challenge is one table for *all* of them. That way you can compute grand totals and individual challenge rankings all with the same table. You'd also want to not record the place directly but compute it on the fly with the appropriate window function depending on how you want to handle ties (`rank()`, `dense_rank()`, and `row_number()` will have different results in those cases); that way you don't have to keep adjusting it as you add new records.

A table something like (You didn't specify a SQL database, so I'm going to assume Sqlite. Adjust as needed.):

```
CREATE TABLE challenge_scores(user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
                              challenge_id INTEGER REFERENCES challenges(id),
                              prize_amount NUMERIC,
                              PRIMARY KEY(user_id, challenge_id));
```

will let you do things like

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             sum(prize_amount) AS total,
             rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(prize_amount) DESC) AS place 
      FROM challenge_scores
      GROUP BY user_id)
WHERE place <= 50
ORDER BY place;
```

for the global leaderboard, or the similar:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             prize_amount,
             rank() OVER (ORDER BY prize_amount DESC) AS place 
      FROM challenge_scores
      WHERE challenge_id = :some_challenge_id
      GROUP BY user_id)
WHERE place <= 50
ORDER BY place;
```

for a specific challenge's.

Comment: its on maria db, which i guess is mysql? I like your answer a lot, very insightful.  So its ok to have the separate reference table for each specific challenge details, that include the date and time for each challenge??  thank you so much, so to be clear a user could have been a winner in multiple challenges so for the global leaderboard i would only want them to show up once on that, and then i see what your doing with the group by challenge id for each challenges leaderboard so this solution works well.

Comment: Also question, i ran the create table, but im confused about their being 2 primary keys???  how is this being done?? thought that would be considered like a composite key.

Comment: Also getting this error when running the query for the leaderboards.MySQL said: Documentation

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias